# How common is it to decipher what type an object is when using socket connections?

Tags: sockets, connection

I've a text game I'm making to give me some practice. I'm to the point where I'm building an overhead map that just shows terrain type for where you're located in the world. The reason I ask this is because I'll be having text and BufferedImages sent to multiple clients connected to a server via socket/serversocket. Now, would it be silly to make two completely different socket connections through different ports to split up my text replies and BufferedImage replies to the various clients, or is it pretty common to decipher what an object is before deciding what to do with it when reading from an objectinputstream? Deciphering the object type would allow me to use just one serversocket connection, I just don't know how proper/practical/good practice that is. I also don't know if sending BufferedImage objects will cause a problem in receiving the text replies from the server promptly. The BufferedImage objects would be about 31x31 pixels in size, so pretty small but I'd be sending up to 9 at a time in a standard array[] type.

Answer (score 1):

It's very common.  In fact, I'd go as far as to say it's required, for any non-trivial remote interaction.  The only question is how you want to go about communicating type information to the program on the other side of the socket connection; there are many ways of doing that, ranging from the simple (send a type-code integer first that tells the receiver what kind of data to expect next) all the way through full-blown object-serialization protocols (things like JSON, XML, Google protocol buffers, and so on).

Comment: How frowned upon is it to let the reciever handle it by doing Object.getClass() comparisons within if statements to decide what to do based on which comparison yields true?

Comment: Nevermind, I think that's the same thing as your type-code integer idea.